# Storing data obtained from Information Extration

Tags: nlp, information-extraction

I have some experience with java and I am a **student** doing my final year project.

I need to work on a project in Natural language processing , well I am currently trying to work on stanford-nlp libraries *(but am not locked to it , i can change my tool) so answers can be for any tool proper for my problem*.

---

I have planned to work on Information Extraction IE , and have seen some page/pdf that explain how it works with various NLP techniques. Data will be processed with NLP and i need to perform Information Retrieval IR on the processed data

**My problem now is: What data-structure or storage medium should I use to store the data I have retrieved by using NLP techniques**

- that data-store must have a capacity to support query
- XML,JSON does not look an ideal candidate . *(i could be wrong)* : if they can be then some help/guidance on best way to do it will be helpful.
- my current view is to convert/store the **parse tree** into a data format that can be directly read for query .(parse tree:a diagrammatic representation of the parsed structure of a sentence or string)

---

a sample of type of data need to be stored , for the text "My project is based on NLP." the [Dependency](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) would be as below

root(ROOT-0, based-4)
poss(project-2, My-1)
nsubjpass(based-4, project-2)
auxpass(based-4, is-3)
prep(based-4, on-5)
pobj(on-5, NLP-6)

Answer (score 1):

Have you already extracted the information or are you trying to store the parse tree? If the former, this is still an open question in NLP. See, for example, the book by Jurafsky and Martin, which discusses many ways to do this.

Basically, we can't answer until we know what you're trying to store. If it's super simple information, you might be able to get away with a simple relational database.

Comment: what am trying to achieve is storing of various NLP processed components like Part-of-Speech,Named Entity Recognition,Coreference,Basic dependencies into some form of data-store which I can later use for querying